# getting null values while loading the data from flat files into hive tables

Tags: hadoop, null, hive, hdfs, flat-file

I am getting the null values while loading the data from flat files into hive tables.
my tables structure is like this:

```
hive> create table test_hive (id int,value string);
```

and my flat file is like this:
input.txt

```
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
5   e
6   F
7   G
8   j
```

when I am running the below commands I am getting null values:

```
hive> LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/hduser/input.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE test_hive;
hive> select * from test_hive;
OK<br>
NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL
```

**screen shot:**

```
hive> create table test_hive (id int,value string);
OK
Time taken: 4.97 seconds
hive> show tables;
OK
test_hive
Time taken: 0.124 seconds
hive> LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/hduser/input2.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE test_hive;
Copying data from file:/home/hduser/input2.txt
Copying file: file:/home/hduser/input2.txt
Loading data to table default.test_hive
Deleted hdfs://hydhtc227141d:54310/app/hive/warehouse/test_hive
OK
Time taken: 0.572 seconds
hive> select * from test_hive;
OK
NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL
Time taken: 0.182 seconds
```

Comment: Probably you need to specify how rows/columns are delimited in your input file when loading into a Hive table. You may try something like: `create table test_hive (id int, value string) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '/user/hadoop/hive/input';`

Comment: Problem you are facing is because in your data the fields are separated by ' ' and while creating table you did not mention the field delimiter. So if you don't mention the field delimiter while creating hive table, by default hive considers ^A as delimiter.

So to resolve your problem, you can recreate the table mentioning the below syntax and it would work.

CREATE TABLE test_hive(id INT, value STRING) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ';

Answer (score 23):

The default field terminator in Hive is ^A. You need to explicitly mention in your create table statement that you are using a different field separator.

Similar to what Lorand Bending pointed in the comment, use:

```
CREATE TABLE test_hive(id INT, value STRING) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ';
```

You don't need to specify a location since you are creating a managed table (and not an external table).

Answer (score 6):

Problem you are facing is because in your data the fields are separated by ' ' and while creating table you did not mention the field delimiter. So if you don't mention the field delimiter while creating hive table, by default hive considers ^A as delimiter.

So to resolve your problem, you can recreate the table mentioning the below syntax and it would work.

`CREATE TABLE test_hive(id INT, value STRING) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ';`

Comment: In the Apache HiveServer2 client example they use a "Ctrl-A" delimited file (a.txt) to load data into table. First of all they don't include this file and second I wish they where providing more info about that.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is quite simple. The Table wan't created in the right way.

Simple solution for your problem or any further problems is knowing how to load the data.

> CREATE TABLE [IF NOT EXIST] mytableName(id int,value string)
>
> ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
>
> FIELDS TERMINATED BY '/t'
>
> STORED AS TEXTFILE ;

Now lemme explain the code :

1. First Line
   Creating your table. The [IF NOT EXIST] is optional that tells if the table exist don't overwrite it. Its more of safety measure.
2. Second line
   Specifies a delimiter at the table level for structured fields.
3. Third Item
   You can include any single character, but the default is '\001'.
   '/t' is for a tab space : in your case
   '|'  is for data which are beside each other and separated by |
   ' ' for one char space. And so on...
4. Forth Line :
   Specifies the type of file in which data is to be stored. The file can be a TEXTFILE, SEQUENCEFILE, RCFILE, or BINARY SEQUENCEFILE. Or, how the data is stored can be specified as Java input and output classes.

when loading Locally :

> LOCD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/your/data/path.csv' [OVERWRITE] INTO TABLE myTableName;

Always try checking your data by a simple select* statement.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Hive’s default record and field delimiters list:

1. \n
2. ^A
3. ^B
4. ^C

press ^V^A could insert a ^A in Vim.

Answer (score 1):

The elements are separated by space or tab? Let it's tab follow these steps. If separated space use ' ' instead of '\t' Ok.

```
hive> CREATE TABLE test_hive(id INT, value STRING) row format
   delimited fields terminated by '\t' line formated by '\n' stored as filename;
```

Than you have to enter

```
hive> LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/hduser/input.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE test_hive;

hive> select * from test_hive;
```

Now you will get exact your expected output "filename".

Answer (score 1):

please check the dataset date column it should follow the date format yyyy-mm-dd
If the string is in the form 'yyyy-mm-dd', then a date value corresponding to that year/month/day is returned. If the string value does not match this formate, then NULL is returned.
[Hive Official documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-date)